# collisionSyntaxError: missing ) after formal parameters

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

I faced with such problem: i've added function to my simple browser game for collect items and earn scores, from Unity Docs:

```
function OnCollisionEnter(collision : Collision) { 
     alert('test'); 
}
```

and I can't get even see my "test" alert. Instead I'm getting the below error

> "Syntax Error: missing ) after formal parameters" with point
>   at " : " after " collision ".

Also I tried `OnTriggerEnter`, but result was the same.

Comment: Is this JavaScript, or...?

Comment: It's Unityscript, of the Unity engine.

Comment: Is this object (may be GameObject) implements a physics class?

    - Is the rigidbody checkbox was checked?

sorry for english.

Comment: sorry for less details, Yeah, It's need to be in JS. 
"Is this object (may be GameObject) implements a physics class? - Is the rigidbody checkbox was checked? " hm... probably.. I need to check documentation once again and read it more carefully, cause i find such way only few hours ago

Answer (score 0, accepted):

reframe your function like this

```
function OnCollisionEnter(collision='Collision') { alert('test'); }
```

Comment: Thank you, it works! So now I will work on this function to collect coins everytime when my car faces with coin. 
Thanks!